# "storing" a specific time with clock

Tags: c++

So I'm wondering if I can use a variable or something and keep the value of `clock` from when it was stored. So for example :

```
if (this)
   that = Clock();
```

So then I can do

```
if (that + 20000)//20 seconds later
     dothing();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: Sure you can. What have you tried doing?

Comment: 1) Is it [`std::clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) you are talking about? 2) if `that` is not an `int` with a value of exactly `-20000` (which doesn't make sense, in the context of `std::clock`), the expression of `that + 20000` is always `true`.

Comment: [Here is a `chrono` video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the `std::chrono` stuff, it has ways to get the current time, add durations to it, and do all sorts of other wonderful stuff.

For example, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;
int main() {
  auto start = system_clock::now();
  while (duration_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now() - start).count() < 5)
    ;
  // It is now 5 seconds later.
}
```

Comment: I guess ill go do that, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

using [sleep_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) in c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>    

int main()
{

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::seconds sec(2);
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(now+sec);
    std::cout << " done "<<std::endl;
}
```